In a dataframe,replace values ​from one column with multiple conditions and not in the same row to another column
I am trying to transfer values ​​from one column to another column in a dataframe, with multiple conditions and not in the same row.
Values from Columns 'BEGUZ_H' and 'ENDUZ_H' to Columns 'BEGUZ' and 'ENDUZ' ,
if the Values in Columns 'PERNR_H' , 'WORKDATE_H' , 'AWART_H'
are equal with the values in columns 'PERNR' , 'WORKDATE' , 'AWART'.
data = {'PERNR': [138888, 138432, 138432, 138437, 138437, 126162, 222829, 234740], 
        'WORKDATE': ['2024-01-25', '2024-01-10', '2024-01-09', '2024-01-26', '2024-01-24', '2024-01-29', '2024-01-15', '2024-01-09'],
        'AWART': [2235, 2235, 2235, 2235, 2235, 2235, 2235, 2235], 
        'BEGUZ': ['00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00'],
        'ENDUZ': ['00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00'],
        'PERNR_H': [0, 0, 126162, 222829, 234740, 0, 0, 138888], 
        'WORKDATE_H': ['NaN', 'NaN', '2024-01-29', '2024-01-15', '2024-01-09', 'NaN', 'NaN', '2024-01-25'],
        'AWART_H': [2235, 2235, 2235, 2235, 2235, 2235, 2235, 2235], 
        'BEGUZ_H': ['NaN', 'NaN', '07:59:00', '07:50:00', '07:03:00', 'NaN', 'NaN', '07:45:00'],
        'ENDUZ_H': ['NaN', 'NaN', '17:30:00', '17:35:00', '18:28:00', 'NaN', 'NaN', '18:59:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
Out[11]: 
    PERNR    WORKDATE  AWART     BEGUZ     ENDUZ  PERNR_H  WORKDATE_H  AWART_H   BEGUZ_H   ENDUZ_H
0  138888  2024-01-25   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
1  138432  2024-01-10   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
2  138432  2024-01-09   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   126162  2024-01-29     2235  07:59:00  17:30:00
3  138437  2024-01-26   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   222829  2024-01-15     2235  07:50:00  17:35:00
4  138437  2024-01-24   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   234740  2024-01-09     2235  07:03:00  18:28:00
5  126162  2024-01-29   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
6  222829  2024-01-15   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
7  234740  2024-01-09   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   138888  2024-01-25     2235  07:45:00  18:59:00

My approach is 'np.where' , but that only works on the same rows.
np.where((df['PERNR']==df['PERNR_H'])&(df['WORKDATE']==df['WORKDATE_H'])&(df['AWART']==df['AWART_H']),df['BEGUZ_H'], df['ENDUZ_H'])

I expect:
    PERNR    WORKDATE  AWART     BEGUZ     ENDUZ  PERNR_H  WORKDATE_H  AWART_H   BEGUZ_H   ENDUZ_H
0  138888  2024-01-25   2235  07:45:00  18:59:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
1  138432  2024-01-10   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
2  138432  2024-01-09   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   126162  2024-01-29     2235  07:59:00  17:30:00
3  138437  2024-01-26   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   222829  2024-01-15     2235  07:50:00  17:35:00
4  138437  2024-01-24   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   234740  2024-01-09     2235  07:03:00  18:28:00
5  126162  2024-01-29   2235  07:59:00  17:30:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
6  222829  2024-01-15   2235  07:50:00  17:35:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
7  234740  2024-01-09   2235  07:03:00  18:28:00   138888  2024-01-25     2235  07:45:00  18:59:00


You could perform a merge and update (saving/restoring the index with reset_index/set_index):
df.update(
    df[['PERNR', 'WORKDATE', 'AWART']]
    .reset_index() # saving the index, merge doesn't maintain it
    .merge(df[['PERNR_H', 'WORKDATE_H', 'AWART_H', 'BEGUZ_H', 'ENDUZ_H']]
           .rename(columns=lambda x: x.removesuffix('_H')))
    .set_index('index')
)

NB. this is assuming at most one match per row.
Output:
    PERNR    WORKDATE  AWART     BEGUZ     ENDUZ  PERNR_H  WORKDATE_H  AWART_H   BEGUZ_H   ENDUZ_H
0  138888  2024-01-25   2235  07:45:00  18:59:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
1  138432  2024-01-10   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
2  138432  2024-01-09   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   126162  2024-01-29     2235  07:59:00  17:30:00
3  138437  2024-01-26   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   222829  2024-01-15     2235  07:50:00  17:35:00
4  138437  2024-01-24   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   234740  2024-01-09     2235  07:03:00  18:28:00
5  126162  2024-01-29   2235  07:59:00  17:30:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
6  222829  2024-01-15   2235  07:50:00  17:35:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
7  234740  2024-01-09   2235  07:03:00  18:28:00   138888  2024-01-25     2235  07:45:00  18:59:00


Split the dataframe in two according to columns names, then merge them back on columns 'PERNR' , 'WORKDATE' , 'AWART' and 'PERNR_H' , 'WORKDATE_H' , 'AWART_H'. Then you can simply replace the values.
df_h = df.filter(regex=r"_H$")
df = df.filter(regex=r"^(?!.*?_H)")

df = df.merge(
    df_h,
    left_on=["PERNR", "WORKDATE", "AWART"],
    right_on=["PERNR_H", "WORKDATE_H", "AWART_H"],
    how="left",
)

df.loc[df["BEGUZ_H"].notna(), "BEGUZ"] = df["BEGUZ_H"]
df.loc[df["ENDUZ_H"].notna(), "ENDUZ"] = df["ENDUZ_H"]

df = pd.concat([df.filter(regex=r"^(?!.*?_H)"), df_h], axis=1)

    PERNR    WORKDATE  AWART     BEGUZ     ENDUZ  PERNR_H  WORKDATE_H  AWART_H   BEGUZ_H   ENDUZ_H
0  138888  2024-01-25   2235  07:45:00  18:59:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
1  138432  2024-01-10   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
2  138432  2024-01-09   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   126162  2024-01-29     2235  07:59:00  17:30:00
3  138437  2024-01-26   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   222829  2024-01-15     2235  07:50:00  17:35:00
4  138437  2024-01-24   2235  00:00:00  00:00:00   234740  2024-01-09     2235  07:03:00  18:28:00
5  126162  2024-01-29   2235  07:59:00  17:30:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
6  222829  2024-01-15   2235  07:50:00  17:35:00        0         NaN     2235       NaN       NaN
7  234740  2024-01-09   2235  07:03:00  18:28:00   138888  2024-01-25     2235  07:45:00  18:59:00

